# StackedColumn chart is flying

Tags: c#, charts, series

I am trying to implement a `StackedColumn` type chart in my project, however I find to understand how to properly assign the different `Series`.

This is demo purpose code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
    {
        string item = "boo" + i.ToString() + a.ToString();

        chart1.Series.Add(item);
        chart1.Series[item].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
        chart1.Series[item].Points.AddXY(i, 100.0);
    }
}
```

However, this produces flying 3 stacked columns instead of 3 equal stacked columns:

[image: flying stacked column]

However, if I remove the `SeriesChartType.StackedColumn` (and use the default) it works just fine and they go to the ground.
How should I make them go to the bottom using `StackedColumn`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently creating a chart with 15 series, each series has only 1 data point. Is this what you are trying to achieve? For example if you wanted to have 3 series, each with 5 data points you should do something like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    // add a series to the chart
    string item = "boo" + i.ToString();
    chart1.Series.Add(item);
    chart1.Series[item].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
    for (int a = 1; a <= 5; a++)
    {
        // add 5 points to the current series 
        chart1.Series[item].Points.AddXY(a, 100.0);
    }
}
```

Comment: well because it is stacked bar what I am try to do is: 3 columns, each having N series on it as on the picture what I have done. The only problem I am encountering is how to make the 2nd stack column go down to the bottom from the start